# financial data get

Tags: finance

I'd like to build a financial software. I want to know if there is public web service to provide data? preferable free. BTW, I don't need real-time data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing Infochimps has 86 data sets tagged *finance*.  Perhaps one of those will meet your needs. [Check it out](http://infochimps.com/tags/finance).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you looking for?

Google and Yahoo provide historic quotes, volumes and closing prices. There are other free providers too. Expect at least 15min delay for real-time data and you would not be able to subscribe to a lot of tickers. Some providers also offer free data API, this is more common for FX products.

You also might want to check out this link: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2008/04/24/25-finance-apis/