# Is here a database for fetching a financial data for capital market?

Tags: python, flask, finance, yfinance, financialinstrument

I am working on some project for automated operations in Python and I need some financial data for Stocks, ETFs etc. I tried several websites to get the data from like Marketwatch, investing etc. but somehow they block my bots and I don't want to break some rules of conduct.

However I am stuck with finding financial data at least for testing period.

Is there any kind of free or cheaper database to get  comprehensive financial data from? (btw. yfinance is not any more functioning and has been officially discontinued)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Cheaper than what? Cheaper is a comparative, you you need to provide a reference.

Comment: May I ask why is my question closed when there are open questions about data resources like [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222671/financial-data-get?rq=2[/link] etc.? Can you please give me hints how do I edit this question/thread? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is tagged python and flask, but you haven't asked any question about python nor flask. Asking for database is language independent, so your question is not really about python, and therefore invalid. If you have a question about python and flask please post it. Otherwise remove the tags